# T SQL Looping on insert or update

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

I  have two tables.

Table A and Table B. The columns are same.

```
create table TableA (
    id int
    , name varchar
    , last datetime
)

create table TableB (
    id int
    , name varchar
    , last datetime
)
```

I m populating table A with mass data. and i would like to either insert or update the data in table A into table B.

I d like to take the data from table A and either insert into table B if id and name doenst match or update if the id and name does match.

I tried some ETL tool but the result was very slow. I have indexing on id and name, I wanted to try this with SQL.

I have the following but not working correct:

```
SELECT      @id = ID, 
      @name = name, 
      @LSDATE = LastSeen_DateTime   
            FROM DBO.A
IF EXISTS (SELECT ID, name FROM DBO.A
WHERE  @ID = ID AND @name = Name)
```

begin
-- update
end
else
begin
--insert
end

i guess i need to put this in a loop and not quite sure how I can make this run.

Thanks.

Comment: the question is to populate Table A to table B, all of the rows in A to B. not a single row. it should be in a loop. for every row in A either insert to B or update a row in B.

Answer (score 6):

Its probably faster to do it two statements one update  and one insert rather than a loop

This statement updates all B rows using the data from A where the ID is the same but the name is different

**Update**

```
Update 
    tableB
SET
   name = a.Name
From
   tableB a
   INNER JOIN tableA a
   on b.ID = a.ID 
      and A.Name <> b.Name
```

This statement inserts all B rows into A where the id doesn't exist in A

**INSERT**

```
INSERT INTO
   tableB
(   ID,
    Name
)
SELECT
   a.ID
   a.Name
FROM 
   tableA b
WHERE
   not exists (Select A.ID From tableB a WHERE a.ID = b.ID)
```

**Updated** (reversed it from A into B rather than B into A)

Comment: the question is to populate Table A to table B, all of the rows in A to B. not a single row. it should be in a loop.

Comment: +1 2 bulk statements is the way I'd go instead of unnecessary and slower looping. Though it sounds like rows should be matched on I'd and name, instead of just id

Comment: @user177883 sorry I had it reversed B into A. I fixed that, but these SQL statements do all rows not one.

Comment: @user177883 - the SQL as provided works on all rows. SQL is *set*-based, not row-based, unless explicitly coded otherwise.

The first statement UPDATEs all B.name values where the IDs match and the names are different, then the INSERT copies all A rows into B where the A.ID value is not in B.

The net effect is that all A data ends up in B.  Perhaps the 'last' column could be added to the statements, but that's trivial.

Comment: And when the poster moves to 2008, he can use the MErge statment instead, but this is the best choice for 2005. Far far better than a cursor or loop which should not even be considered for this type of task.

Answer (score 6):

If you were using SQL Server 2008 (or Oracle or DB2), then you could use a merge statement.

```
MERGE B
USING A AS source 
ON (B.ID = source.ID and B.Name = source.Name)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET Last = source.Last
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (ID, Name, Last) VALUES (source.ID, source.Name, source.Last)

   -- the following is optional, if you remove it, add a semicolon to the end of the above line. 
   OUTPUT $action, 
   inserted.ID AS SourceID, inserted.Name AS SourceName, 
   inserted.Last AS SourceLast, 
   deleted.ID AS TargetID, deleted.Name AS TargetName, 
   deleted.Last AS TargetLast ;
```

The bit with the "output $action" will display what rows are getting updated and what rows are getting updated.

weasel words: I recognize this isn't *exactly* what you were looking for, but since others may search this topic, it may be helpful for others in the future.

Comment: @Conrad, I have no clue about performance. We use 2008 in development with 2005 in QA and production, therefore the code I have to have production run sometimes looks like your answer and sometimes like Will's answer. The production servers are in a datacenter about 2k miles away and are run by rather hostile folks, and they have to understand everything I send them before they run it. None of our dev and QA servers have large enough hard drives to show any real difference.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @id int
DECLARE @name nvarchar
DECLARE @last datetime
DECLARE TableA_Cursor CURSOR FOR
    select id
            , name
            , last
        from TableA;

OPEN TableA_Cursor;

FETCH NEXT from TableA_Cursor 
INTO @id, @name, @last;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        IF (EXISTS select 1 from TableB b where b.Id = @id)
            update TableB
                set Name = @name
                    , Last = @last
        ELSE
            insert into TableB (Id, Name, Last) 
                values (@id, @name, @last)

        FETCH NEXT from TableA_Cursor
        INTO @id, @name, @last
    END

CLOSE TableA_Cursor;

DEALLOCATE TableA_Cursor;
```

There may be some syntax error, particularly around the `IF` condition, but you may get the point.

Comment: +1 for providing a loop even though it probably isn't the way to go

Comment: This is not a task in which you should consider using a cursor.

Comment: @Conrad Frix: Personaly, if I had to do what the OP asks, I would for sure go with two separate statements as you suggested. In fact, that is what I was writing when I received the new-answer update. After seeing what you suggested, I couldn't keep up with my solution as it would have been a "copy", if you see what I mean. So, I figured out another one with a loop.

Comment: @HLGEM: Yes, and this approach is a second thought, as my first option would go with Conrad Frix's answer. But the OP seems to stick with his loop, so I provided a loop. This for sure would work, it all depends on the resources available from the data server, and the amount of data to process. But this would work, so it is an available solution.

Comment: Don't forget that you have to `FETCH NEXT` within the `WHILE` loop.

Comment: @Sean Bright: Absolutely! I completely forgot! Thanks for the highlight! I'm going to edit. =)

Comment: Edited to include `FETCH NEXT` within the `WHILE` loop! =)